# Why do I have to modify the web.config to enable debugging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-config

Why would it not automatically be enabled?

i.e. What are the disadvantages to enabling debugging in the config file? There must be some, otherwise surely it would be enabled by default.

For context, see tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would it not automatically be enabled?

Security and performance reasons - it is easy to forget to do this on a live web server, which is not a good idea.

Running in debug mode is *much* slower than in release mode. It also exposes more information in the [YSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_of_death). It is better to be [secure by default](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_by_default) than the alternative...

Comment: So I suppose to understand why this isn't a good idea I should understand the implications of debugging being enabled on a live server - which I don't. I thought the only way to debug was effectively through visual studio on the actual solution. Thanks, +1.

Comment: i uploaded on production site manually setting `debug=false`, you mean because of that site will be fast, ok but visual studio ask [this](http://i.imgur.com/32JEiTI.jpg) option always in local when not in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you don't want your users to be seeing the custom error messages that debug mode returns, so debug mode should be set to true when in development and false when it is released. Best practice is to use designed 'friendly' error screens after release.

Comment: Thanks @ReiMasuro - same comment as on Oded's answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Are these custom error messages you refer to the yellow error messages in the browser?

Comment: When debugging is enabled the yellow messages state specifics of what has gone wrong and where, where turned off they just present a generic failed message, IIS can be set to display designed pages in place of these for a more professional look.

Answer (score 1):

when in debug=false
it will omit many debug information used not necessary in release

Comment: What form does this information come in though? I think I need to learn a little more about debug=false vs. debug=true in live versions. Thanks. +1.